# How to include an additional CMakeLists.txt

Tags: search, include, cmake

Say we have a command call `foo` in CMakeLists.txt which is in folder `/A`.

`foo` is defined in antother CMakeLists.txt which is in folder `/B`.

How can one reference to `/B/CMakeLists.txt` from within `/A/CMakeLists.txt` in order to call `foo`?

I tried to set search paths to `/B/CMakeLists.txt` via:

- `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`
- `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`
- `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`

but none of them worked.

CMake still complaines `Unknown CMake command "foo".`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

That can be done with [`include`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html), here's some simple example:

Content of A/CMakeLists.txt

```
function(foo)
    message(STATUS "heya")
endfunction()
```

Content of B/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../A/CMakeLists.txt)
foo()
```

Now, including another CMakeLists.txt will also run everything in that file, so you may want to avoid doing that if there are targets in B/CMakeLists.txt

If you can modify your code, it would be better to define your functions in a "top level" CMakeLists.txt before calling `add_subdirectory`.

Answer (score 51):

If this files just contains functions definitions you should not call it CMakeLists.txt, but some_adequate_name.**cmake**

Than you can include it where you need those functions definitions using [`include`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html).