# CMakeLists + gtest

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I have a directory tree in my project:

```
/project
   /build
   /src
         main.cpp
         student.cpp
   /include
         student.hpp
   /test
         main_test.cpp
         CMakeLists.txt
   CMakeLists.txt
```

Also I have my gtest and gmock libraries in:

```
/home/karol/Google
              /gtest
              /gmock
              /lib
```

I'm wondering whether I should move the `project/CMakeLists.txt` to the `src/` directory?

My goal is to have a choice between compiling the binary file or the unit tests. I would like to know how the CMakeLists would have to look like to achieve this.

Comment: The problem you've faced with is unclear. You may go either way: leave CMakeLists.txt in project/, move it to project/src/ or create an additional CMakeLists.txt in project/src/. Depending on what you're trying to achieve every of these ways may be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your `project/CMakeLists.txt` add:

```
add_subdirectory  (test)
add_custom_target (testing)
add_dependencies  (testing main_test)
```

In your `project/test/CMakeList.txt` add:

```
add_executable    (main_test EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL main_test.cpp)
```

Now, if you type just `make` binary files will be build, but if you type `make testing` unit tests will be build.

Answer (score 0):

Your CMakeLists.txt file should stay in the root of your project not in the folder of your main sources. You can specify the sources and/or the projects directly by CMake.

Anyway if the test/CMakeLists.txt is another project (or gtest's one) you should not touch it but rather [add_subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) it from CMake.

If that file contains reusable functions then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17228677/1938163)

Comment: not sure if `include` is the solution for adding CMakeLists.txt, rather it's for `*.cmake` files

Comment: @PiotrS. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:include -> file|module. Anyway the add_subdirectory is a better choice (include should be aimed for reusable functions). I'll edit this but I had no idea on the nature of those files.

Answer (score 0):

In your main `project/CMakeLists.txt` just use the following command:

```
add_subdirectory( test )
```

it will include all the targets from `test` directory, and those targets will be accessible while building your project.

Now, assuming your `gmock` directory is outside of your project hierarchy, you should do what follows, in your `project/test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory( /home/karol/Google/gmock gmock )

include_directories(
    ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

add_executable(
    test_exec
    test.cpp # list the cpp files with your tests
)

target_link_libraries(
    test_exec
    gmock_main
)
```