# Reading variables into cmake from another CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

Using `Ubuntu`, `C++` and `cmake`, I want to create a program `Alpha` which is based upon code for another program,`Beta`. I already have the source code for `Beta`, and I need to write code for `Alpha` which uses this existing code. I am trying to keep everything neat, so I have a separate directory for `Alpha` and `Beta` source files, `Alpha.cpp` and `Beta.cpp`.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/CMakeLists.txt
/Alpha.cpp (the main function)
/Beta
    /CMakeLists.txt
    /Beta.cpp
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` file for `Alpha` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Alpha)
add_executable(Alpha Alpha.cpp Beta/Beta.cpp)
```

Now, in the original code for `Beta`, the `CMakeLists.txt` file has lots of information, such as checking the operating system, finding packages, and generally defining various cmake variables. I need to use those variables in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for `Alpha`, so that `Beta.cpp` is compiled properly.

So, my question: is it possible to retain all of this information in `Beta/CmakeLists.txt`, without having to write it all out in `Alpha`'s `CMakeLists.txt` file? How do I then tell `Alpha`'s `CMakeLists.txt` file to read `Beta`'s `CMakeLists.txt` file to get these variables? I want to do this to keep everything neat, and to maintain modularity. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CMake has an `include` construct which will allow you to pull in other files/modules.
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html

So you could separate out whatever you need from Beta/CMakeLists.txt into another file/module called Beta.cmake and include it in Alpha's CMakeLists with `include (Beta/Beta.cmake)`.

So your directory structure would be

```
/CMakeLists.txt
/Alpha.cpp (the main function)
/Beta
    /CMakeLists.txt
    /Beta.cmake (variables required in Alpha's CMake)
    /Beta.cpp
```

And the Alpha's CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Alpha)
include(Beta/Beta.cmake) (get variables needed from Beta)
add_executable(Alpha Alpha.cpp Beta/Beta.cpp)
```

Also see [How to include an additional CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228677/how-to-include-an-additional-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: Thanks. In your example, why would I still need `Beta/CMakeLists.txt` if all its variables are now in `Beta/Beta.cmake`?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the third line in Alpha's CMakeList.txt be `include(Beta/Beta.cmake)`?

Comment: Whether you want to include all of `Beta/CMakeLists.txt` or not depends on how much of that information you need for the Alpha's CMakeLists.txt. The idea is to extract the common items required by both and put in a separate file and have them included.

Comment: Yes, CMake should be able to find Beta.cmake either by specifying the path of having CMAKE_MODULE_PATH specified. I've fixed the typo.

Comment: Thank you. But what would remain in Beta's CmakeList? The variables that were originally needed to compile Beta are now in Beta.cmake, and the only other commands are those to do with creating the Beta executable, such as add_executable(Beta Beta.cpp). I am no longer creating an executable in the Beta folder, just using the sources and cmake variables in there to make the Alpha executable. Can you give an example of what might still need be in Beta's CMakeList?

Comment: Sometimes, the Beta directory might create a shared object or dll so it will have some settings of its own. In your case that doesn't seem to be the case.