# Build C library with CMakeLists.txt while packaging python library

Tags: python, c, cmake, cython, setup.py

I use Cython to wrap C library and extend its functionality. C library is developed by separate team and is provided with CMakeLists.txt. For now I use source .c and .h files to build this library. This is how my `build.py` file for poetry (`setup.py` analog) looks like:

```
...
# source_files_paths - list of full paths to .c files
c_library = ('c_library', {'sources': source_files_paths})
...
def build(setup_kwargs):
    setup_kwargs.update({
        ...,
        'libraries': [c_library],  # Here c library is built with build_clib command
        ...
    })
```

Is it possible to use `CMakeLists.txt` to build `c_library` in `build` function (or in `setuptools.setup` function)?

**UPD:** It is also ok for me to define variable that is used in .c files. I tried to add `define_macros`:

```
c_library = ('c_library', {'sources': source_files_paths,
                           'define_macros': [('MY_MACRO': True)]})
```

Still no luck with it.

**UPD2:** I finally found the solution to my problem though it is not the answer to my initial question. To add macros you should add it in this way:

```
c_library = ('c_library', {'sources': source_files_paths,
                           'macros': [('MY_MACRO': True)]})
```

According to `build_libraries` function from http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Lib/distutils/command/build_clib.py you can also specify 'include_dirs', 'obj_deps' and 'cflags' arguments.

Comment: At work I wrote up some scripts to build my cmake project using python. I was able to do this using the subprocess module in python. Which allowed me to build my cmake project easily from python. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The [scikit-build](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package can replace setuptools and it is able to use CMakeLists.txt. (See [Basic Usage guide for scikit-build](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage)). It can do [CMake with Cython](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmake-modules/Cython.html).

Comment: I tried this out but could not find the way to build underlying C-library with it. As I could understand it can only build Cython package cmakefile, not the chain of cmake files. Could you please provide me an example if I am wrong?

Comment: Moreover, could not find how to use it with poetry

Comment: What happens when you add the CMakeLists instructions for the C library directly into the CMakeLists.txt used to build the Cython code? Try including this text manually, or use the instruciton [_include_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228677/how-to-include-an-additional-cmakelists-txt).